# Bottom table row goes to top

Tags: html, html-table

I have the following table code that each row contains a form. My problem is, the bottom row, where the input and submit are, is going to the top above the top table row. I cannot figure out why. Can someone please help and explain why the bottom row goes to the very top?

```
<table id="bet_table" width=800px cellspacing=0 cellpadding=1 border-width=1px>
    <tr bgcolor="BF1919" style="color:#fff; font-weight:bold;">
        <td><center>Time</center></td>
        <td><center>Game #</center></td>
        <td><center>Teams</center></td>
        <td><center>Run Line</center></td>
        <td><center>Money Line</center></td>
        <td><center>Total Runs</center></td>
    </tr>
    <tr bgcolor="#F0F0F0">
        <td colspan=6><center><strong>August 28, 2012</strong></center></td>
    </tr>
    <tr bgcolor="#fff">
        <form action="mlb.php?action=update&gameid=" method="post" />
        <td width="130px"><center><input type="text" size="4" name="time" value="7:00" />
        <select name="ampm">
            <option value="AM">A.M.
            <option value="PM">P.M.
        </select></center></td>
        <td width="60px"><center>306</center></td>
        <td>Los Angeles Dodgers<br />Los Angeles Angels</td>
        <td width="150px"><center>                          
        <select name="runline1frac">
            <option value="-1/2">-1&frac12;
            <option value="+1/2">+1&frac12;
        </select> &nbsp; <input type="text" size="4" name="runline1value" value="+120" /><br />
        <select name="runline2frac">
            <option value="-1/2">-1&frac12;
            <option value="+1/2">+1&frac12;
        </select> &nbsp; <input type="text" size="4" name="runline2value" value="-182" /></center></td>
        <td width="80px"><center><input type="text" size="4" name="moneyline1value" value="-132" /><br /><input type="text" size="4" name="moneyline2value" value="+132" /></center></td>
        <td align=right>Total Runs: <input type="text" size="3" name="totalruns" value="6" /> &nbsp; OV &nbsp; <input type="text" size="4" name="totalrunsOvalue" value="-178" /><br />UN &nbsp; <input type="text" size="4" name="totalrunsUvalue" value="+123" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr colspan=6>
        <center>
            <input type="submit" value="Update" />
            </form>
        </center>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pasted your code and fixed it here:

http://jsfiddle.net/5nNxB/

Your last `<tr>` did not have a `<td>`. Added it with the right `colspan`.

As a side note, your code is not very clean. Wrap the entire table in `<form>` instead of randomly inserting the tags in the middle. Also, try not to use inline styling and attributes like `bgcolor` etc.

Comment: Thanks so much! I had not even realized that! Studied it for 10 minutes and didn't see it, thanks!

Comment: Glad it helped. :) Does that answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

Bottom of your code :

```
<tr colspan=6>
    <center>
       <input type="submit" value="Update" />
       </form>
    </center>
</tr>
```

Should be:

```
<tr>
    <td colspan=6>
        <center>
           <input type="submit" value="Update" />
           </form>
        </center>
    </td>
</tr>
```

The `form` tag also is placed incorrectly

Comment: How do you fix the form? Thanks.

Comment: <form>
  <table>
  </table>
</form>

Place table in form tag.

Comment: But your button goes on top of table becouse you assigned attribute colspan to <tr> tag, not to <td>

Comment: Well every two rows will have a different form depending on the game ID. So I can't put out the form on the top because every 2 rows is a different form. So should the form tag stay like that?